# how to run gnome-terminal on remote centos 7 machine?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, gnome

My local machine is linux mint, and remote one is centos 7.
I try to open gnome-terminal on remote machine with x-forwarding, and its not working.

When I connect to host in interactive mode

```
$ ssh -Y centos-host
```

Then in opened session I can run gnome-terminal and x-forwarding working

```
$ gnome-terminal 
$ netstat -nltp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

However when I try yo run

```
$ ssh -Y centos-host gnome-terminal
```

The window with gnome terminal opened, but no tunnel for X created.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I have an another linux mint remote machine, and not experienced such problem with it. So, I think something wrong with centos 7.

Please, help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `gnome-terminal` forks itself into the background. If you run it in your interactive `ssh` session, you will notice that you get a new command prompt even though the terminal is still open. In the non-interactive case, as soon as this happens, `ssh` will think the command has terminated and closes the session, including closing the listening X11 socket on the server. Since there are still active X11 connections, `ssh` doesn't exit immediately, which is why it *looks* as if the session is still active, however no new X11 connections can be opened.

You used to be able to do this by using `gnome-terminal --disable-factory`, however this has unfortunately been removed from `gnome-terminal` at some point. You have two options now:

- Use another terminal program that doesn't fork into the background, for example `xterm`
- Directly after starting `gnome-terminal`, in the same `ssh` session run a command that doesn't terminate, for example `ssh -Y server 'gnome-terminal; echo Press enter to exit; read'`

Comment: thank a lot, the fork of the gnome-terminal was a problem. I wrote script that runs gnome-terminal and do sleep until he died. now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration:

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

The following commnand works for me:

```sh
ssh -Y HOST bash -l -c gnome-terminal --display=${DISPLAY} < /dev/null > /dev/null  2>&1 &
```

The `gnome-terminal --disable-factory` informed me `--disable-factory` was no longer supported.

Comment: Great answer (but I was still able to improve it a bit, ha). Welcome to the site Mike.